# Continuity of the function $F(y)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}ye^{-(x-y)^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, continuity, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

$$F(y)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}ye^{-(x-y)^4}dx,\text{while } y>0 $$
My attempt: We have $D = [0;+\infty)\times (0;+\infty)$, but let's consider $\overline D = [0;+\infty)\times [\delta;+\infty), \delta > 0$. As $ye^{-(x-y)^4}$ is continuous on $\overline D$, if I prove uniform convergence here $\forall \delta > 0$, I'll get that $F(y)$ is continous on $\overline D$, hence it's continuous on $D$. So my problem is to find majorant 'cause I think it's the problem on Weierstrass test. But I really can't find it. I tried to differentiate but it didn't help much, so I'm completely stuck

Comment: Try the substitution $z=x-y$.

Comment: How will it help? I got $\int\limits_{-y}^{+\infty}(x-z)e^{-z^4}dz$

Comment: $F(y)=y\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^4}dx=y\int_{-y}^{\infty} e^{-z^4} dz$ which is obviously a product of two contuniuous functions.

Comment: I don't understand why is it obvious that $\int\limits_{-y}^{+\infty}e^{-z^4}dz$ converges uniformly

Comment: This integral has no parameters, so what do You mean by "uniformly"?

Comment: But $z=z(y)$ as $z=x-y$. What happened when we made that substitution that we can't bother anymore about $z$? Is it because $dx$ became $dz$? As everywhere we have $z$ we can say that's everything is ok?

Comment: It's the purpose of the substitution, to obtain some simplification. In this case we were able to extinct the parameter from the integral. The cost of this is that we now have a non-constant lower limit. But this is not much trouble, because the integral is a continuous function of ist lower (or upper) limit.

Comment: By the way, nobody asked about the uniformly convergence of the integral. It's the way which You tried to go, but it's not a shortest way. So I proposed another way, where uniformly convergence doens't play any role.